# Two-Body Problem and Finding the Ellipse Axis

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

Okey, so the thing is: I was doing some exercises about two body central force problems and there is this question about two particles attached by a spring. They tell you that at a certain moment the particles are a certain distance d apart, each with the same velocity but different directions (one to the left, the other upwards). They ask you about the Semi-major and semi-minor axes **a** and **b** of the ellipse created by the relative vector r that joins both particles.

Now **my approach**: With the data given I've found the energy, which must remain constant, and then I've written down the expression for the energy when the radial velocity is zero. Once done that, and taking into account the value of the energy and the angular momentum remain constant, I found that for r<sub>12</sub>=d(1±1/2)<sup>1/2</sup> the radial component of the velocity is zero. That is, the distance from the focus for which the velocity is only angular.

**My question**: I think that the semimajor axis of the ellipse created by the reduced-mass relative motion would be just the sum of r<sub>1</sub> and  r<sub>2</sub> divided by 2, but there is this solution I found that treats the next problem (finding the period) as if **a** and **b** were just r<sub>1</sub> and  r<sub>2</sub> respectively. Is my reasoning right or am I misunderstanding  something?

I guess the best would be just writing the problem in case I didn't express myself correctly:

> Two particles of mass m atract each other due to a force with the given expression **F**=-*k***r**, where *k* is a positive constant and **r** is the vector of the relative position between the two bodies. Initially the bodies are found in the situation depicted by the figure, where *$$v=d\sqrt\frac{k}m$$* Find the semimajor axis and semiminor axis of the relative orbit that describe the two bodies and its period[image]